# Map thumbnail in DialogFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I'm ripping my hair out trying to display a thumbnail sized map in either an AlertDialog or preferably in a SherlockDialogFragment.

I have this in my xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

And with just this in my `SherlockDialogFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    getDialog().setTitle(offer.retailer);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.businesstmpalert, container, false);
    return v
}
```

I get an `Error inflating class fragment` error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are nesting fragment (`MapFragment` inside a `DialogFragment`) AND specifying the `MapFragment` in the `<layout>`.

From http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

You could either nest the fragment programmatically:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.map_fragment_host, MapFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

in `DialogFragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`, or (preferably, IMHO) switching to `MapView`, which you can safely use as a `<layout>`. In this case, remember to propagate fragment lifecycle events to the `MapView`, as specified in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

1-Add these lines a the end of the  within manifest file.

if this not work then...

2-extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```